# Parsing an xmlhttpresponse to retrieve a value

Tags: parsing, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

I've managed to read the response but I've been stuck for hours now trying to just get the "balance" value.

How do I parse out just the 23 number? (that's the balance in this case)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="data"></p>

<script>

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("data").innerHTML =
     xhttp.responseText;

        
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://api.reimaginebanking.com/accounts/576d55170733d0184021f510?key=081e7c77daa22967b857b3152e3ff2f1", true);
 xhttp.send();


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to retrieve balance with `JSON.parse`:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        var objResp = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = objResp.balance // 23
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://api.reimaginebanking.com/accounts/576d55170733d0184021f510?key=081e7c77daa22967b857b3152e3ff2f1", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Or you can even use `eval` method, but that solution is not so reliable since responce might contain malicious code which will be executed:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        var objResp = eval('('+xhttp.responseText+')');
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = objResp.balance // 23
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "http://api.reimaginebanking.com/accounts/576d55170733d0184021f510?key=081e7c77daa22967b857b3152e3ff2f1", true);
xhttp.send();
```